# check for string format in bash script

Tags: bash, grep

I am attempting to check for proper formatting at the start of a string in a bash script.

The expected format is like the below where the string must always begin with "ABCDEFG-" (exact letters and order) and the numbers would vary but be at least 3 digits.  Everything after the 3rd digit is a do not care. 
Expected start of string: "ABCDEFG-1234"

I am using the below code snippet.

```
[ $(echo "$str" | grep -E "ABCDEFG-[0-9][0-9][0-9]") ] && echo "yes"
```

str1 = "ABCDEFG-1234"

str2 = "ABCDEFG-1234 - Some more text"

When I use str1 in place of str everything works ok and yes is printed.

When I use str2 in place of str i get the below error

```
[: ABCDEFG-1234: unary operator expected
```

I am pretty new to working with bash scripts so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The smallest change necessary to make your code work would be just to add quotes and a `-n`: `[ -n "$(echo "$str" | grep -E "ABCDEFG-[0-9][0-9][0-9]")" ] && echo "yes"` -- that way the output from `grep` isn't string-split and passed to `[ ]` as separate arguments, which was the immediate cause of your error. That said, that approach is unnecessarily inefficient and baroque, when `grep` can directly emit a true or false exit status based on whether it matched, with no need for `[ ]` or output parsing at all, and when the shell can do comparisons without needing any external tool like grep.

Comment: (...and the `-n` is only necessary in some pathological cases; in the common case, the quotes would be enough).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is bash, you have no reason to use grep for this at all; the shell has built-in regular expression support.

```
re="ABCDEFG-[0-9][0-9][0-9]"
[[ $str =~ $re ]] && echo "yes"
```

That said, you might want your regex to be anchored if you want a match in the beginning rather than anywhere in the content:

```
re="^ABCDEFG-[0-9][0-9][0-9]"
[[ $str =~ $re ]] && echo "yes"
```

That said, this doesn't need to be an ERE at all -- a glob-style pattern match would also be adequate:

```
if [[ $str = ABCDEFG-[0-9][0-9][0-9]* ]]; then echo "yes"; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `grep -E "ABCDEFG-[0-9][0-9][0-9].*"`

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem, which is due to failing to quote the output of `grep` into a single token for being passed to `test`. (Of course, if one used `grep -q` and ran `if echo "$str" | grep -q -E ...; then...`, then it'd be moot; involving `test` at all is overcomplicating things unnecessarily).